# "across" vs. "in" in "animals are likely to be introduced 'across'/'in' the market"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> Currently available GM fruits stem mostly from plants, but in the
>   future foods derived from GM microorganisms or GM animals are likely
>   to be introduced *across / in* the market.

Note:  **GM** means Genetically modified.

I'm pretty sure that *in* makes sense here. But I's unsure when my friend used *across the market*. Is *across* is apt here?

Comment: @JR: *PS* is not formal here?

Comment: It's not a formality issue, I just thought "Note" fits better than "PS", especially when it's in the middle, as opposed to the [very end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript), of the question.

Answer (score 5):

I think either preposition could be used, although they have slight differences in meaning:

- ...*in the market* would mean that GM foods will be made available.
- ...*across the market* would carry the additional inference that the introduction would be widespread (using *in* wouldn't preclude that, but the word *in* wouldn't necessarily infer a widespread introduction, either).
- ...*to the market* would also be an acceptable preposition.

This is one of those cases where there isn't a single correct preposition. Because prepositions are such versatile words, examples of that aren't all too uncommon.

Comment: What about *at the market*?

Comment: @Sudhir That would imply they're being introduced at a single market (ie. one store). "The market" here is an abstract idea, not a physical place.  You can't be *at* the abstract concept of "the market", you can only be *at* a physical place. So that changes the meaning to something you don't intend.

Comment: As @Wendi explained, "at" is not a good word to use. However, one might use ["on"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+market).

Comment: Its the best answer and explanation